# Should multiple step forms be arranged vertically or horizontally?

Tags: forms, information-architecture, wizard

I'm designing a 4 step insurance form.

1. enter details
2. view your quote
3. etc. etc.

Someone has asked why have we done vertical steps (i.e. finish step 1 and move onto new page step 2).

Now we know users don't mind scrolling and long pages are in-fact okay. would it perform better if we implemented as vertical steps instead? i.e. as you finish step 1, it moves the user down the page instead?

Answer (score 3):

I would say it depends on the complexity of your form. If each steps contains at most 3-4 questions and most of the questions are pretty much self explanatory and straight forward, i.e. do not require a lot of help text, then you should implement the form as vertical steps instead. That would save users a few clicks. Otherwise, you could opt for one step per page.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically right when you say that users don't mind scrolling, but as NNGroup points out:

> Web users spend 80% of their time looking at information above the page fold. Although users do scroll, they allocate only 20% of their attention below the fold. 
>   (http://www.nngroup.com/articles/scrolling-and-attention/)

In the same article, they point out that (in articles) it's better to do scrolling than paging, *"because it's easier for users to simply keep going down the page than it is to decide whether or not to click through for the next page of a fragmented article"*.

What I conclude from it is:

- articles - use scrolling.
- step-by-step forms - use paging

These are of course no static rules, but they give a good starting point.

Like donysukardi mentioned in his answer, it depends a lot on the complexity of your form. The [Wizard Pattern](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Wizard) can also work if all steps are on the same page (doesn't matter if horizontally or vertically arranged).
If

- the steps are *separated into logical or functional groups*,
- you provide the *next* and *previous* navigation elements and
- you're having as few steps as possible

you'll be facing no major problems. But personally, I'd go with the standard way.